# How do I apply a filter in Wireshark so I can trace a session in which more than one Final-Unit-Indication AVPs have been sent?

Tags: packet-capture, wireshark-dissector, diameter-protocol

I have a capture with some Diameter traffic, my question is if there is any way in which this filtering can be done?

Comment: Sorry for bad English, I'm not a native speaker

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://wiki.wireshark.org/DIAMETER)?